# Batch Conversion of PaperPort MAX Files

Tags: batch, images, conversion, scanner

I've got a library of MAX files from an old Visioneer Scanner that used ScanSoft PaperPort. I don't have the PC that I used to scan them anymore, and I don't have the CD for PaperPort. Does anyone know of a utility I can use to open and convert .MAX files to something more useful like a JPEG?

(I'd prefer something that batch converts -- but if I can get a utility that will even allow one conversion, I could probably figure out how to use AutoHotkey or something like that to automate.)

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't found it already, there is a free PaperPort Viewer available at ftp://ftp.scansoft.com/pub/program/paperport/setupex.exe which is a Windows executable but runs fine for me under Wine.

This doesn't really do any conversions, but at least it makes things readable.  I suppose if you are really desperate you could grab a screen image and feed that through an OCR utility.